# I can't login with Facebook Socialite in Laravel API/Passport (Sorry, something went wrong.) error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to implement Facebook login via socialite For Laravel API using passport:

api.php:

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
    //Social Login
    Route::get('login/google', [LoginController::class, 'redirectToGoogle']);
    Route::get('login/google/callback', [LoginController::class, 'handleGoogleCallback']);
    Route::get('login/facebook', [LoginController::class, 'redirectToFacebook']);
    Route::get('login/facebook/callback', [LoginController::class, 'handleFacebookCallback']);

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        
    });
});
});
```

LoginController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;



class LoginController extends Controller
{
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        return response()->json([
            'token' => Auth::user()->createToken('UserApp')->accessToken,
        ]);
    }

    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
    ]);
}

protected function _registerOrLoginUser($data)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $data->email)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $data->name;
        $user->email = $data->email;
        $user->provider_id = $data->id;
        $user->avatar = $data->avatar;
        $user->save();
    }
    Auth::login($user);
}
protected function _registerOrLoginUserFacebook($data)
{
    $user = User::where('facebook_id', $data->id)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $data->name;
        $user->email = $data->email;
        $user->facebook_id = $data->id;
        $user->save();
    }
    Auth::login($user);
}

// Google Login
public function redirectToGoogle()
{
    return Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->redirect();
}

public function handleGoogleCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();

    $this->_registerOrLoginUser($user);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $accessToken = $user->createToken('UserApp')->accessToken;

    return response()->json([
        'token' => $accessToken,
    ]);
}

// Facebook Login
public function redirectToFacebook()
{
    // return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect();
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
}

public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();

    $this->_registerOrLoginUserFacebook($user);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $accessToken = $user->createToken('UserApp')->accessToken;

    return response()->json([
        'token' => $accessToken,
    ]);
}
}
```

services.php:

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_REDIRECT'),
],

'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_REDIRECT'),
],
```

.env:

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=Hidden
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=Hidden
GOOGLE_REDIRECT=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/google/callback

FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=Hidden
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=Hidden
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT=http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login/facebook/callback
```

In the above there are two functionalities for login one for Google and the other for Facebook.

Google login is working fine but I'm facing an issue with Facebook login.

When I go to 'api/auth/login/facebook' I get this from Facebook:

[image]

In Facebook developer dashboard I checked App ID and APP Secret and both are correct.

Also 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs' and 'Redirect URI to Check' fields in Facebook developer dashboard are empty because localhost automatically allowed:

[image]

So what seems to be the issue?

Comment: What does the actual URL look like that you are on, when you get that "something went wrong" error from Facebook?

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=hidden&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code`

Comment: Do not use an IP address in your redirect URL, that does not work well with Facebook apps - use a host name.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that these days, it no longer seems possible to have facebook login apps properly redirect to a non https local uri like: `http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback`

You have 2 alternatives though:

1. Run your site on a local domain, with https, on a test domain like: `https://mydomain.test`

This can be achieved with tools like:

- [Laravel Herd](https://herd.laravel.com/docs/1/advanced-usage/securing-sites) (use: `herd secure`)
- [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/valet#securing-sites) (use: `valet secure`)
- [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#sharing-your-site) (use: `sail share`)

2. Run your site on a local domain, with https, on a ngrok domain like: `https://xxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ngrok-free.app`

To do this, install ngrok from [their site](https://ngrok.com/) (it has a free version) and run the following commands:

```
php artisan serve
ngrok http 8000
```

Then your terminal will show you an HTTPS url, which you can use in your .env and the facebook developer dashboard

See this guide on the whole process:
[Login to Your Laravel App With Facebook Using Socialite](https://laracoding.com/login-to-your-laravel-app-with-facebook-using-socialite/) (disclaimer: this is a link to my own website and guide)